# Nested AJAX calls in jQuery Templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have a jQuery Template that is rendering a list of comments:

```
<script id="CommentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="Entry" id="${ID}">${Comment}</div>
</script>
```

This is being populated by a AJAX call and is working fine. I want to add a list of replies asynchronously. I would like to trap the event when this template content is rendered and append the replied to the `Entry`. Is there a way to call a JS function, say `ShowResults(id)` populated by `${ID}` when each `Entry` is rendered?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging I found a pretty elegant solution. You can pass an set of key value pairs to the template via the `options` parameter in the [`tmpl` signature](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/). I pass a function call as shown below:

```
$("#CommentTemplate").tmpl(result, {
    LoadReplies: function (key) {
        GetReplies(key);
    }
}).appendTo("#CommentsListing");
```

Then in the `GetReplies` I do an AJAX call and apply to a second template. Worked like a charm.